# How to get "grep -isrl"-like results for files in analogous subfolders?

Tags: regex, grep

I am working with a certain framework which has modules with consistent folder naming conventions. I would like to retrieve all files containing partial string `foo` from a high level directory, but I only want results from files with a path containing a directory named `Bar`. To elaborate: from the root directory of the project, there are generally four levels of subfolders, containing an arbitrary number of subfolders and text files all .php). The subdirectories in which I would like to search / from which I would like results all contain a parent folder named `Bar`.

Stated relative to my limited experience: I would like a command such as `grep -isrl 'foo' ./` and only receive results such as

```
./A/B/C/Bar/D/F/Some.php
./G/H/I/Bar/Some.php
```

and excluding

```
./A/B/C/Baz/D/F/Some.php
./G/H/I/Baz/Some.php
```

Essentially, I assume there's something like `grep -isrl 'foo' ./*/Bar/*.php` where `*` will match zero-to-many subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
find <search path> -type d -name 'Bar' -exec grep -r foo {} +
```

(without GNU find, replace `+` with `\;`).

This way will first find the directories that are named `Bar` and then recursively grep only in these.

To limit the search to PHP files:

```
find <search path> -type d -name 'Bar' -exec grep -r --include '*.php' foo {} +
```

---

It could also be done with shell globbing, but that depends on which shell you are using (obviously).

**EDIT:** Adding a Bash example:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -r test <search path>/**/Bar/
```